# How can I modify this JavaScript regex that checks if a string is a number that must have maximum 2 decimal digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am pretty new in JavaScript regex and I have the following problem.

Into a JQuery script which I am working on, I have the following regex which seems to check if the value into the **variazioneAnticipo** variable is a decimal number:

```
var variazioneAnticipo = $("#variazioneAnticipo").val();

if (/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/.test(variazioneAnticipo)) {
    ..................................................
    ..................................................
    DO SOMETHING
    ..................................................
    ..................................................
}
```

I think that it means that the previous regex respond true for any concatenation of digits from 0 to 9 (the integer part of the number) that can be concatenated to the **.** symbol (the decimal separator) followed by any string composed by the digits from 0 to 0 (the decimal section).

So it will accept string as:

105 or 105.1 or 105.12 or 105.1231243123123123131231

Ok, how can I modify the previous regex to accept only strings that represent numbers with maximum 2 decimal digits?

So for example:

**105 must be accepted**

**105.1 must be accepted**

**105.12 must be accepted**

but:

**105.123 must not be accepted**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add repeatation or range quantifier next to `\.[0-9]`..

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

`[0-9]{1,2}` should match either one  or two digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `^\d+$|^\d+\.\d+{2}$` , `this.checkValidity()`

```js
$("#variazioneAnticipo").on("input", function() {
  if (this.checkValidity()) {
    $("label").html("");
    var variazioneAnticipo = $(this).val();
    console.log(variazioneAnticipo
                ,this.checkValidity());
  } else {
    $("label").html("invalid input")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="variazioneAnticipo" class="rightAlligned form-control" style="width: 60%" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" value="${progetto.impAcc}" pattern="^\d+$|^\d+\.\d+{2}$"/>
<label></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression below matches only numbers with maximum 2 decimal digits.

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

To a better explanation [click here](https://regex101.com/r/uV6uI6/1)

If you want customize it just modify the [range of the repetitions](http://regexone.com/lesson/repeating_characters). ex:

1. Modify **N** and/or **M** to change the range of decimal numbers accepted.

   ^\d+(?:.\d{N,M})?$
2. Modify **N** and/or **M** to change the range of integers accepted.

   ^\d{N, M}(?:.\d{1,2})?$

Follows the snippet applying the related regex to the javascript [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instruction.

```js
function testRegex(){
  var data = $("#digits").val();
  if(/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(data))
    alert("It's ok");
  else{
    alert("Sorry, it's not a valid input");  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="digits" />
<button onclick="testRegex();" type="button">Test it</button>
```